# VC++ system() function

Tags: visual-c++

I am using VC++ for my work. I have to open a video file using VC++. i have created batch file, writng command "start wmplayer path of the videofile in wmv format"and coverted my bat file into exe format. I used system() function to open my exe file. I have completed my work. Last week I purchased new laptop and I installed Microsoft Visual studio 2010 same as of my old laptop. the same code is not running in new one. no errors are coming. the code is been build. but the video is not playing. but if i click the batch file or exe file video is running.

1. I ceated bat file for my video. I created new txt doc and saved as .bat file. in that i wrote as 
   start wmplayer "path of the video file" /fullscreen.
2. I convert this bat file into .exe file using bat to exe converter
3. i wote program in VC++ (Visual studio 2010 IDE)

   #include
         #include
         #include

   ```
    int main()
          {
           system("path of the .exe file");
           getch();
           return 0;
          }
   ```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Yes, add your code. Otherwise it will be impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the code you want:

```
int main()
{
  system("wmplayer \"path of the video file\" /fullscreen");
  return fgetc(stdin);
}
```

Because the 'command' has quotes in they need a backlash to "escape them" otherwise they will be treated as the start and end of a string and it will all go wrong.

I haven't actually compiled this, it should work, if it doesn't paste the compiler output.

This is the most basic and least elegant of solutions, but it will to start with.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this one. No errors. but till now video is not running. Just wmplayer is openend.

Comment: Thank you. I got solution for that problem. I saved my .exe file in Windows folder in C:. now the code is working. Thank you